# FormData & Axios : Send a file to a Node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, axios, form-data

In Vuejs, I have a picture drag and drop code. I have tried, without success, to send the file to NodeJS using FormData and axios like many example in the web e.g.

```
export default function(url, file, name = "avatar") {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append(name, file);

  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
  };
  return axios.post(url, formData, config);
};
```

The issue come from the client side not from server 
see https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/548
and
https://gist.github.com/HarshithaKP/ebc0e79800e5638fe827c157360378be

I also tried with a classic input and it works

```
<form ref='uploadForm' 
  id='uploadForm' 
  action='https://localhost:4000/api/upload/picture' 
  method='post' 
  encType="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="sampleFile" />
    <input type='submit' value='Upload!' />
</form>
```

I came to the conclusion : the header of Axios is incomplete.

Some people advice to complete the header by using the form-data library https://github.com/form-data/form-data

```
headers: {
   ...form.getHeaders(),
   'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
}
```

But in form-data, the library use for client the classical object FormData (https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/FormData) without the function `getHeaders()`. It doesn't exist. In the code, we have
`module.exports = typeof self == 'object' ? self.FormData : window.FormData;`

**QUESTION**

How can I populate properly the header in order that the server reconize the POST with a file ? A kind of a `getHeaders()` function.

Comment: What is the error you're encountering anyway?

Comment: On server side, req.file is undefined using multer ou express-fileupload. It works with an input balise

app.post('/api/upload/picture', function(req, res) {
  if (!req.files || Object.keys(req.files).length === 0) {